# Considering the odd mass number rule, how does $\ce{^{14}{N}}$ NMR work?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

In my high school chemistry class, we learned that NMR only works for nuclei with odd mass number. Hence, we often use the $\ce{^1{H}}$ and $\ce{^{13}{C}}$ spectra. However, on [this page about NMR I read](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Magnetic_Resonance_Spectroscopies/Nuclear_Magnetic_Resonance/NMR%3A_Experimental/NMR_-_Interpretation#:%7E:text=Nuclear%20Magnetic%20Resonance%20(NMR)%20interpretation,%2C%20coupling%20constants%2C%20and%20integration.), it says that $\ce{^{14}{N}}$ is also used, but with a mass number of 14, this evidently violates what we learned in class.

What am I missing here? Is the "odd mass number" thing just a simplification? If so, what's the actual criteria for whether or not something can be used for NMR?

Comment: A better way of saying this is that a nuclei with a non-zero spin is NMR active. This means that the nuclei must have an odd number of neutrons and/or protons. N-14 has a spin of 1, so it is NMR active.

Comment: See this link. This answers your question in detail. https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/spectrpy/nmr/nmr2.htm

Comment: An odd mass/nucleon number guarantees one of proton or neutron number is odd as well (odd + even = odd). Therefore the mandatory  NMR condition of  the nonzero nucleus spin is met. nitrogen-14 as the double odd nucleus (odd + odd = even) meets this condition by 2 ways.  BTW nitrogen-14 is it the heaviest (2H, 6Li, 10B, 14N) stable odd-odd nucleus (with one exception of metastable isomer tantalum-180m1)

Comment: For an even simpler example, $^2\ce{H}$ NMR is also possible

Comment: Your high school chemistry class was wrong. It's not NMR active if it has an even number of protons and an even number of neutrons. Otherwise, active. Having an even mass number does not imply this condition, but having an odd mass number immediately implies the opposite.